# Having trouble with writing a .txt flie

Tags: java

So I am having trouble getting my program to not throw NoSuchElement exceptions at me. When I input the owner info, it throws the exception after the second owner no matter which owner I input:

```
Jones; 221 Smith St; Arlington; Texas; 76019

Smith; 7345 Lane Rd; Dallas; Texas; 75000

Willis; 596 Dale Lane; Fort Worth; Texas; 76123
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WriteFile
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Formatter output;
    try
    {
        output = new Formatter("owners.txt");
        System.out.println("file accessed");

        System.out.println("Please enter owner information. Separate     information with semicolons please:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            try
            {

                String owner = input.nextLine();
                String[] tokens = owner.split(";");

                output.format("%s %s %s %s %d%n",input.next(), input.next(), input.next(), input.next(),input.nextInt());
            }

            catch(NoSuchElementException ee)
            {
                System.out.println("Error on input. Please try again.");
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }

        output.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error working with file");
    }
}
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: You should probably use the `tokens` variable in the `format` call, and don't call `nextLine` in the `catch`. Also consider how you expect the loop to end.

Comment: Can you update your question with exactly what you are attempting here?  Do you want to write the input to file or just format it for display to the console?  As it stands now, your code almost has too many problems for the question to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
output.format("%s %s %s %s %d%n",input.next(), input.next(), input.next(), input.next(),input.nextInt());
```

The calls to read the next tokens are reading nothing, since your earlier `input.readLine()` has already gobbled up the entire line. You should be using your `tokens[]` object in the formatter.